# Wrote a TicTacToe in Shell and the compute is not playing nice

Tags: bash, shell, tic-tac-toe, minimax

The computer always plays in the first empty place and I don't know why. When I play on place 1, the computer plays in place 2 and so on. If the minimax function always return 1, wouldn't change anything. What's happening?

Note: My board is 1 to 9. and check_win give me 10 if computer won, -10 if the human, 0 if a tie, if the match not end "false".

```
#!/bin/bash

best_move(){
    local best_score=-1000
    for (( i=1; i<=${#board[@]}; i++ ))
    do
        if [[ ${board[$i]} =~ $re_isnumber ]]; then
            board[$i]=$computer
            local score=$(minimax 0 "false")
            if [ $score -gt $best_score ]; then
                best_score=$score
                local move=$i
            fi
            board[$i]=$i
            
        fi
    done
    board[$move]=$computer
    current_player=$human
}


minimax(){
    result=$(check_winner)
    if [[ $result == 10 ]]; then
        echo result
        return
    fi

    if [[ $result == -10 ]]; then
        echo $result
        return
    fi

    if [[ $result == 0 ]]; then
        echo $result
        return
    fi
    
    if [[ $3 == "true" ]]; then
        maximize
    else
        minimize
    fi
}

maximize(){
    local best_score=-800
    for (( i=0; i<${#board[@]}; i++ ))
    do
        if [[ ${board[$i]} =~ $re_isnumber ]]; then
            board[$i]=$computer
            local score=$( minimax $(($2+1)) "false" )
            if [ $score -gt $best_score ]; then
                best_score=$score
            fi
            board[$i]=$i
        fi
    done
    echo $best_score
}

minimize(){
    local best_score=800
    for (( i=0; i<${#board[@]}; i++ ))
    do
        if [[ ${board[$i]} =~ $re_isnumber ]]; then
            board[$i]=$human
            local score=$(minimax $(($2+1)) "true")
            if [ $score -lt $best_score ]; then
                best_score=$score
            fi
            board[$i]=$i
            
        fi
    done
    echo $best_score
}
```

Comment: You might also run it through http://shellcheck.net/ and fix what that finds.

Comment: More importantly, though: can you try to narrow this down to a specific question about why the shell itself isn't behaving the way you expect, instead of a general "please debug this program" request? Something like `PS4=':$LINENO+' bash -x yourscript` might be appropriate, to get a line-by-line log of how the script is operating so you can identify the specific place its behavior differs from your expectations, and thereby ask a more specific question focused on that problem.

Comment: It's #!/bin/bash, hope this is reply you first comment .I don't knew these tools, I'll do it. Thanks.

Comment: You are just showing a bunch of function, but not how the game is actually started.

Answer (score 0):

If your program is returning the first spot it is because it doesn't find a better move than that. I won't debug the whole program for you, but the most common reason it does this is because you send the wrong evaluation score back. I am not familiar with your language, however it seems like you are always sending back a score of 10/-10 if you get a certain result from check_winner. The score sent back needs to be dependent on whose turn it is. E.g. you need to send back a winning score of 10 if 'O' is winning AND if it is 'O' turn. If 'O' is winning AND it is 'X' turn, you need to send back a loosing score of -10.